# UserControl/ElementHost Transparent Background

Tags: wpf, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I need a method that sets the background of the ElementHost completely transparent or so that it does not even render in the first place.

[image]

### Current Structure

In the background I have a PictureBox. 
Over that there is my UserControl (Which you can Download below). 
Both the PictureBox and the UserControl have a Width of 150. 
As you can see in the Picture above, the UserControl is 100% Invisible. 
In the UserControl is an ElementHost with a Width of 120, within that there is a WPF-Content with a Width of 100. 
Everything is Transparent, except the ElementHost1.

### My Code

**UserControl:**

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
    Get
        Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        cp.ExStyle = &H20
        Return cp
    End Get
End Property

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub Refresh()
    Parent.Invalidate(New Rectangle(Me.Location, Me.Size), True)
End Sub

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
    Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent

    ElementHost1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent
    ElementHost1.BackColorTransparent = True
End Sub
```

I´ve also tried to create a **Custom ElementHost:**

```
Public Class TransElementHost
    Inherits ElementHost

    Public Sub TransElementHost()
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
        Me.BackColorTransparent = True
        'Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.ExStyle = &H20
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Refresh()
        Parent.Invalidate(New Rectangle(Me.Location, Me.Size), True)
    End Sub
End Class
```

[My SVGTest-UserControl](https://mega.co.nz/#!7Y9z1arL!EFVPPFFuNlgLowDDlB_sXvIPwXW_lgC96DD9IKdulvc)

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Try `[control name].Parent = PictureBox1`.

Comment: @VisualVincent Its Kinda gone now. (Just invisible)
And in Term of later use, I can´t use such an Answer. Since I ultimativly want to use the SVGTest-Control over an SVGTest-Control. So I gain the function of loading SVG in a WinForm. ^^

Comment: I know it's been a while, and I don't know if you still need help, but I found these two links: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.backcolortransparent(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d897f814-918d-46a2-8a02-d93fdafe733f/elementhost-control-inside-winform-with-trasparent-backcolor?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: Sadly it didnt helped. I already set those Properties. But I still need help. The Project is currently set on Ice, until I find a new Method to resolve this.

Comment: Try asking on the MSDN Forum too. They've helped me out in tricky situations. :)

Comment: And after more than two months I've gotten a solution. :) (I haven't worked on it for two months, but I needed something similar and was able to find a solution)

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been really long since this was active, but if you still need it I've (finally) got a code that will draw controls' backgrounds fully transparent.

Just put this code in the control's code. It overrides the `OnPaintBackground` event:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaintBackground(e)

    If Parent IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim index As Integer = Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(Me)

        For i As Integer = Parent.Controls.Count - 1 To index + 1 Step -1
            Dim c As Control = Parent.Controls(i)
            If c.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Bounds) AndAlso c.Visible = True Then
                Dim bmp As New Bitmap(c.Width, c.Height, e.Graphics)
                c.DrawToBitmap(bmp, c.ClientRectangle)
                e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(c.Left - Left, c.Top - Top)
                e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, Point.Empty)
                e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(Left - c.Left, Top - c.Top)
                bmp.Dispose()
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is that all you have or is there something else? What properties are set for the ElementHost?

Comment: @darbid : That is all, I'm afraid. To be honest I've never actually tested this with an `ElementHost`, but it works with other controls.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I’m pretty sure it does not work for an element host.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the best fix, but you could try using the `ButtonRenderer` class. Put this code either in `OnPaintBackground` or `OnPaint`.

```
If Me.BackColor = Color.Transparent Then
    Windows.Forms.ButtonRenderer.DrawParentBackground(e.Graphics, Me.ClientRectangle, Me)
End If
```

The `ButtonRenderer` class is used to draw the regular buttons; their border, background, text, image etc.

I used the above code myself to create a custom control with transparent background. (Though I see now that my control inherits from `ButtonBase`... But the above code is still worth a try).

Comment: Nothing really changed, except that the ElementHost-Background is now the Background of the Form, e.g. white. It shall not have the Color of the Parant. It should be invisible, so that, as you see above, the Image is visible. And just the ElementHost does Problems.

Comment: Anyone got an new idea? @Visual-Vincent

Comment: @Sonorpearl : Sorry. I don't :/. - And sorry for the late reply.